# Issue with Submodules and ArgoCD 1.5.3

Tags: argocd

I have an issue with submodules since I upgraded my ArgoCD server from 1.3 to 1.5.3.

I want to deploy an app using manifests defined in one repo that has a second repo as a Submodule.

I don't need that ArgoCD tries to clone the submodule when executing ArgoCD commmands from the CLI. It is a behaviour added from ArgoCD v1.4 (Submodules are now supported and will be picked up automatically.
[1](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/user-guide/private-repositories.md#git-submodules)).

I tried setting the environment variable ARGOCD_GIT_MODULES_ENABLED=false, however I still see the error that argocd tried to check out the submodule and was denied access.

Has anyone encountered the same issue and successfully deactivated this new behaviour?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have added your application to argocd with source config use https method like that:

```
source:
  repoURL: 'https://gitlab.com/my-group/test-service.git'
  path: deployment/dev
  targetRevision: develop
```

and submodule is configurated to authenticate with ssh method.

So, argocd will use https is default method for fetching submodule from git repository, and your submodule can not be access by https method, and this issue occured

I have the same issue, so i change `repoURL` from https to ssh method, like this `git@gitlab.com:my-group/test-service.git`, and authenticate for whole parents and submodule git reposiotry in argocd repositories manager, and I have resolved my issue.